# disallow multiple logins of a user session in websphere

Tags: websphere

My application is deployed in IIS which has plugins to connect to websphere where my application servers are spinned up. Websphere connects to LDAP for user auth. I have a requirement to have ONLY one user session allowed through websphere. If same user identity tries to login again on the same or other device or anywhere there should be some setting / configuration in websphere should prohibit user to make second session. Any direction on this matter will be helpful.

Comment: How does your application authenticate?  Are you using form based login with j_security_check (jee standard) or home grown solution? There is nothing out of the box, so only custom solution could be developed.

Comment: hi @Gas - yes, you seem to be right. also its j_security_check based login with user password. do you have any direction /sample to restrict access for multiple users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using standard WAS security with form based login, you could take a look into this Redbook [WebSphere Application Server V7.0 Security Guide](https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg247660.pdf). In the chapter "8.8 Customizing the login process" it shows filter that you could use for customizing login process. More detailed approach is also shown here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-nd/8.5.5?topic=login-developing-servlet-filters-form-processing

In very high level:

- you need db with table where you keep your current logins and login times (to provide some timeouting in case one doesnt log off properly)
- in filter you check if given user has active concurrent login and return error page instead or pass through to the app.

This is very high level and you need to design it correctly to not lock out your users. E.g. user accidentally closing his browser would result with having to wait for the timeout before being able to log in again.

Another approach could be to logout any existing sessions, and log in just new user, but that approach requires you to have distributed session invalidation, which is also not an easy design.

So in short, I'd think twice if it is really required feature before implementing it, as it adds a lot of complexity to your applicaion ;-)

Comment: Hi, how can i kill logged in user session on WebSphere from java servlet application.

Comment: What do you want to do? You can just call session.invalidate() to invalidate session.

Comment: hi Gas..thanks for your response. Actually in my case, User1 logs in to site with his creds then if User2 logs in to site using the same creds then i need to show User2 that "there is already an active session" so for this, i would like to query existing session for logged in user from websphere. I am really having hard time finding any native library to return me sessions stats from Websphere. I am not sure but if i do session.getSession (userid) in servlet then i think it gives browsers wide session. So getSession will return null if User2 tries from diff  machie even if user1 is logged in.

Comment: So for my clarification, Can you guide me if HttpServeletRequest - session.invalidate() or session.getSession() will really handle my scenario on once machine across one type of browsers / diff type of browsers between chrome and firefox .. or will HttpSession.getSession give me session details from server even if i try to log in from different machine? Thank you again!

Comment: Well thats why I told you that it is very complex design. You have to track sessions by yourself in global hashmap (userid, sessionlist) in each server and manually manage this. More over if you have cluster, you would have to synchronize invalidations between all cluster members eg either using distributed cache for that (dynacache) or messaging(pub/sub) or some other way.